# React's async with enzyme and expect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I am using mocha, enzyme and expect for my testing. I have a function in my component that runs another function which returns a promise and I don't know how to test behaviour of the 1st one before it runs the 2nd function and later on test the promise (get error after .then)

1st function:

```
handleUpdateInput (value) {
    const { access, onUpdateInput } = this.props
    const v = !value || typeof value === 'string' ? value : access(value)
    if (onUpdateInput) {
      onUpdateInput(value ? v : '')
    }

    this.setState({
      searchText: value
    })

    this.dataSourceUpdate(value)
}
```

2nd function:

```
dataSourceUpdate (value) {
    const { promise, access } = this.props

    if (value === '') {
      this.autoCompleteData = []
      this.setState({ dataSource: [] })
    } else {
      promise(value)
        .then(res => {
          this.autoCompleteData = res.data
          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.autoCompleteData.map(access).slice(0, getMenuItemNumber(this.refs.customAutoComplete))
          })
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.autoCompleteData = []
          this.setState({ dataSource: [] })
        })
    }
  }
```

I would also appreciate sending me a good tutorial for testing async functions with these tools :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the promise from props (thats a good think), you can mock your promise using sinon.

For example, you could try:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'); // you can use any Promise module here

var deferred = Promise.defer();
stub = sinon.stub(deferred, 'resolve').returns(deferred.promise);

deferred.resolve({res: { data: 'YOUR_DATA' }});
// or
deferred.reject(new Error('fake error'));
```